# Verilog : Are there any good sites contains open source projects?

Tags: fpga, verilog, open-source

i was wondering if there are any good sites who encourage open source in the fpga world using code in verilog or vhdl?

since the open source community is very powerful and all the big firms contribute to it with great modules in software, is there any similarity in RTL codes?

Comment: This question is too open-ended.  There are dozens of sites with open source projects, and "good" is subjective.  Also, you've repeatedly asked questions without properly capitalizing anything. Finally, please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677541/verilog-and-open-source-are-there-any-good-sites-contains-open-source-projects).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Open Cores](http://opencores.org/) has a collection of open source Verilog/VHDL cores.